# iOS13 Issue with extra large padding at the top of table view controller

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, ios13

I've been scratching my head over this one, and can't figure out how to remove the extra padding/inset at the top of my uitableviewcontroller. The UITableView is configured to be a style of Grouped.

I have read somewhere they have added more padding at the top. but shouldn't it not add any padding if there is a section title in place?

I've tried setting the scrolling content insets to never as well but doesn't help at all.

[image: iOS13 Bug]

Comment: Is this a UITableView Group header?

Comment: @FreakyAli yes, RECENT MATTERS is the  section's group header title. it's the firs section of the group

Comment: Does the solution given below work for you?

Comment: @FreakyAli not it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in the UIViewController which contains the TableView

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
   base.ViewDidLoad ();


   // init the UITableView firstly 

   if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11,0))
   {
      tableview.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior =  UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.Never;
   }

   else
   {
     this.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;               
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried this already before and it has no effect on this.

Comment: You can share your sample which contains the issue and I will check it on my side .

Comment: here's the snippet of my view, but it's hard to share the entire csproj sample as there's a lot of couplied packages and dependencies all from our internal solutions.

Comment: And storyboard as well:

https://www.codepile.net/pile/Vzy1drzr

Comment: I've also got some customizations to the header view, where I override the UITableViewSource https://www.codepile.net/pile/E1REvW9W

Comment: I saw that you set the Margin-Top of Header as 20.0 and its height as 20 .

Comment: yeah I tried playing with the margin it has no impact either. The height of 20.0 for the header is an estimated header, as the main height is using AutomaticDimension's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200396/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-wpa).